# Code keeps shutting down when it shouldn't and seems to ignore IF statement (Not sure, very new to Batch)

Tags: batch

I'm trying to make a batch file to backup Dark Souls 3 Save Directory before launching the game, then I launch the game, then I check if the game is running and backup again and wait 900 seconds before doing it again and close the program when the game is not running.
This is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Backup Save Dark Souls III
@ECHO We are locating the save folder
:: go to DS3 directory
cd  %APPDATA%
cd C:\Users\Alec\Documents
mkdir DarkSoulsIII
:: reset to C: root
cd/ 
XCOPY /y /e  C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Roaming\DarkSoulsIII    C:\Users\Alec\Documents\DarkSoulsIII

@ECHO launch DS3
:: jump to drive
D: 
@ECHO locating DS3 game directory
cd "D:\Steam Library\steamapps\common\DARK SOULS III\Game\" 
@ECHO D:\Steam Library\steamapps\common\DARK SOULS III\Game\
START DarkSoulsIII.exe
TIMEOUT 10

:check_and_backup
@ECHO Checking if the game is still running
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq DarkSoulsIII.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    @ECHO Game is running backup 
    cd C:\Users\Alec\Documents 
    mkdir DarkSoulsIII
    cd/ 
    XCOPY /y /e  C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Roaming\DarkSoulsIII    C:\Users\Alec\Documents\DarkSoulsIII
    @ECHO Backup Completed
    TIMEOUT 900
    GOTO    :check_and_backup
)

PAUSE
```

The problem I'm having is that if I add an ELSE GOTO EOF the program shuts down even if the Dark Souls III.exe is still running.
Another problem that I like the xcopy inside the IF is even doing anything
I tried the following:

```
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq DarkSoulsIII.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    @ECHO Game is running backup 
    cd C:\Users\Alec\Documents 
    mkdir DarkSoulsIII
    cd/ 
    XCOPY /y /e  C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Roaming\DarkSoulsIII    C:\Users\Alec\Documents\DarkSoulsIII
    @ECHO Backup Completed
    GOTO :check_and_backup
    TIMEOUT 900
) ELSE (
    GOTO EOF
)
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring the advice I gave you on your (now deleted) identical copy of this question?

Comment: Please read [Debugging batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) and [edit] your question.

Comment: And also, why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your previous question, but I understand you've made good progress with your attempts so far, congratulations.

But consider its the title *.." seems to ignore IF statement"...* , brings the possibility of being confused with a question involving that same command, so (supposedly) your question has a high probability of being close (or equal) to the previous one and be closed...

The fact that it's new in batch didn't need to be said, that your code spontaneously exposes this and please, receive it with good eyes, I've been there, if I compare myself with some here, and still I'm there if I compare myself with others here, it's part.

I'll try to tell you what your code is doing, and at the same time propose some options, and along the way I hope you come to understand why your `if` isn't your problem.

---

**1.** If when running/calling bat it is in a different driver than your `%AppData%` or `%UserProfile%` folders, then use **`/d`** (got to driver) in your `cd` command.

> ```bat
> :: go to DS3 directory 
> :: why go to folder 1: cd /d "%APPDATA%"
> :: do noting there?
> :: why go to folder 2: cd /d "%UserProfile%\Documents"
> ```

---

**2.** You can create the folder using the full path and already omitting the warning your folder exist using `2>nul`, and you not needing to enter it to create the folder.

> ```bat
> @ECHO We are locating the save folder
> ...
> mkdir "%UserProfile%\Documents\DarkSoulsIII" 2>nul
> ```

- **Obs.: 1** Your bat doesn't need to go to any folder to run `mkdir`, `tasklist`, `if` , `xcopy`, etc...

---

**3.** No need to go to drive `c:`, and/or any to folder or go down from drive, if your `xcopy` command is getting the full paths to folders/drivers.

> ```bat
> :: ------------------------------------------- remove next 4 lines -------- :: 
> ::reset to C: root 
> cd/ 
> XCOPY /y /e  C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Roaming\DarkSoulsIII
> C:\Users\Alec\Documents\DarkSoulsIII
> :: ------------------------------------------- use /i in xcopy command ---- ::
> XCOPY /y /e /i "%AppData%\DarkSoulsIII"  "%UserProfile%Documents\DarkSoulsIII"
> ```

---

- **Obs.: 2** Try run `xcopy /?` and check the flag `/I`

```bat
If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
```

---

**4.** Run `start` pointing to the executable folder `/d "d:\FullPath\Folder\`
`executable` and call this run `start` with `/b` if necessary.

> ```bat
> @ECHO launch DS3
> :: ------------------------------------------- remove next 7 lines -------- ::
> :: replace lines ::
> :: jump to drive
> D: 
> @ECHO locating DS3 game directory
> cd "D:\Steam Library\steamapps\common\DARK SOULS III\Game\" 
> @ECHO D:\Steam Library\steamapps\common\DARK SOULS III\Game\
> START DarkSoulsIII.exe
> :: -------------------------------- use start "in" /d "D:\Path\" executable ::
> :: start "" /b /d "D:\Steam Library\steamapps\common\DARK SOULS III\Game\" DarkSoulsIII.exe
> ```

- **Obs.: 3** Use `start "in" /b`<sup>**ackground**</sup> so that your bat will continue to run, with the other actions on its next lines, otherwise the commands below will wait for the start to finish and then continue. But keep in mind that this is not a rule for all executables, some return to bat and continue, but others don't...

---

**5.** There is no `errorlevel` return for the `tasklist` command that can satisfy and/or be usable in an `if` condition:

> ```bat
> :check_and_backup
> @ECHO Checking if the game is still running
> TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq DarkSoulsIII.exe"
> IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (do if true) else (do because it is false)
> ```

- If found or not (running or not), you get the `errorlevel == 0` condition for all the test bellow:

> ```bat
>                (call ) & TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq Not_Running.exe" & echo\%errorlevel%
> cmd.exe /v /c "(call ) & TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq Not_Running.exe" & echo\!errorlevel!"
> cmd.exe /v /c "(call ) & TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq Not_Runnung.exe" & echo\!errorlevel!"
> ```

- Each command above return ErrorLevel `0` (2nd line => 0):

> ```bat
> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria. 
> 0
> ```

- **Obs.: 4** For the record, when running with running `explorer.exe` returns the same ErrorLevel `0`:

> ```bat
> >cmd.exe /v /c "(call ) & TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq explorer.exe" & echo\!errorlevel!
> :: tasklist output:  Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
> :: tasklist output:  ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
> :: tasklist output:  explorer.exe                  3420 Console                    1    104,072 K
> 0
> ```

- **.Obs.: 5** If you try using the `&&` and `||` operators, where `&&` implies action if the previous command `return 0`, and/or `||` action if previous command `return non 0`, also does not work:

> ```bat
> >TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq Not_Running.exe" && pause
> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
> Press any key to continue . . .
>
> >TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq Not_Running.exe" || pause
> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
> ```

---

**8.** Remove `mkdir ...` is duplicate command from above on line 7.

> ```bat
> IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
>    ...
>    mkdir DarkSoulsIII  // remove line
>    ...
>   )
> ```

---

**9.** Using system variables and adding the redirect (`|`) to the `find` command and replacing `if` with operator `||` (`return non zero`).

> ```bat
> @echo off
>
> setlocal 
> title Backup Save Dark Souls III
> call :check_and_backup DarkSoulsIII.exe
>
> :check_and_backup
> Checking if the game is still running
> >nul tasklist /nh /fo csv | find /i "DarkSoulsIII.exe" || (
>    echo\Game is Running Backup 
>    mkdir "%UserProfile%\Documents\DarkSoulsIII" 2>nul
>    xcopy /y /e /i "%AppData%\roaming\darksoulsiii" >"%UserProfile%\documents\darksoulsII"
>    echo\Backup Completed
>    if /i "%~nx1" == "DarkSoulsIII.exe" 2>nul ( 
>         start "" /b /d "D:\Steam Library\SteamApps\Common\Dark Souls III\Game\"  DarkSoulsIII.exe
>         timeout /t 900 /nobreak 
>         exit /b >
>       )
>        timeout /t 10 /nobreak 
>        goto :check_and_backup
>    )
>   
> goto :eof & endlocal & pause
> ```

**Obs.: 6** Using system variables `%AppData%` & `%UserProfile%`

> ```bat
> Your can replace literal path to: 
> C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Roaming\DarkSoulsIII    
>             %AppData%\Roaming\DarkSoulsIII
>
> C:\Users\Alec\Documents\DarkSoulsIII
> %UserProfile%\Documents\DarkSoulsIII
> ```

**Obs.: 7** You can use your `:label` in two ways, one initial using the call and passing the name of the `DarkSoulsIII.exe`, and letting the label check if any arguments `%~1` were passed to start or not the `DarkSoulsIII.exe`, and if it is not running, run `xcopy`, and also while doing the corresponding timeout.

> ```bat
> call :check_and_backup DarkSoulsIII.exe
> ....
> if /i "%~nx1" == "DarkSoulsIII.exe" 2>nul ( )
> ```

**Obs.: 8** For some commands in cmd/bat (third-party executables as well), the errorlevel may behave corresponding to the action of the command, not exactly referring to the obtained results, in these cases, handling the redirected command output may be more precise than the result itself, where I suggest using `find` or (`findst`, `more` and/or others), along with the operator operators `&&` and/or `||`, in your case for `errorlevel 1` the operator of `return non 0` == `||` for your specific case.

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Xcopy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [`Tasklist /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`If condition() else condition()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Variable and Substring Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [Command line parameters in batch file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)
- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file)
- [DelayedExpansion (Refer: `!Expand_RunTime_Variable!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)